# Flutter Can't get assets to work on my pupspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

Am trying everything to get my asset - images to work inside my pupspec.yaml and failed every time.I tried changing my folders writing my way to the folders other ways inside my 'assets:' and nothing worked.Even when i tried uploading the font_awesome_flutter dependence i failed.So i think something is wrong with my flutter or with my entire pupspec.yaml

pupspec.yaml:

```
name: fluttertest
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:


  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


 

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - assets/images/client.jpg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

```
flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.20.0-7.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale el-GR)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

folder structure:inside flutter project,assets,images,client.jpg

Answer (score 0):

YAML files are sensitive to whitespace and you need to always ensure your indentation is correct. In you case it is not correct. `assets:` should be indented 2 spaces under `flutter:`.

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/client.jpg
```

Another possible issue(though this is likely a typo) is that the file should be named `pubspec.yaml`, not `pupspec.yaml`.